# Decorating Intermediate Classes in Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

In protobuf-net, which base class should be decorated? The class being directly subclassed or the furthest base class? Or both?

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(42, typeof(Derived))] // Here?
public abstract class BaseClass { }

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(42, typeof(Derived))] // Or Here?
public abstract class Intermediary : BaseClass { }

[ProtoContract]
public class Derived : Intermediary { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate parent of each expected sub-type, not the ancestor.

So: `BaseClass` needs to declare `Intermediary`, and `Intermediary` needs to declare `Derived`:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(42, typeof(Intermediary))]
public abstract class BaseClass { }

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(42, typeof(Derived))]
public abstract class Intermediary : BaseClass { }

[ProtoContract]
public class Derived : Intermediary { }
```